# Shiny Plot interaction with chartseries

Tags: r, plot, quantmod

Is it possible to add plot interactions such as zooming as shown [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/plot-interaction-zoom.html) and panning to charts plotted with the `chartseries` function from quantmod?

I am trying to find a decent yet simple solution for charting financial data (mainly candlesticks) with R. The standard `chartseries` plots are ok but severely lack a nice zooming functionality. I've use DYGRaphs and gvis packages but they struggle with plotting a non-continuous timeseries on the x-axis (i.e they have gaps in the data for weekends.) Gvis can over come this by using a discrete x-axis but then you lose the dates as labels. The other issue with these is that they dont have the nice integration of the indicators and trades on the plot that quantmod gives you.

I'm fairly new to R, but after spending several days exploring all the options for charting financial data and not finding a half decent solution, I think I'm barking up the wrong tree. Is there any sort of industry standard that I've completely missed?

Comment: Have you tried plotly? It's probably the easiest to get started with, and is a bit more flexible than dygraphs.

Comment: Similar issues with Plotly as mentioned above. It cant include all the nice portfolio analytics and trade indicators that quantmod offers without a good amount of messing around. This can be done, but I'm surprised with all the effort that's gone into those packages that a better all encompassing solution for financial data hasn't been made!